# Display dates in color based on condition

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a date column in a table (panel group layout). Now I want to display Dates in red colour which are 15 days  less than current date and Dates in green colour which are 15 days greater than current date. Kindly share the groovy expression to be used for this.

Comment: Hey Vignesh, i'm writing the answer but as a side note, know that you're suppose to show the code you tried in your question to facilitate our help. (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do so is to have a java public function returning the currentDate minus 15 days in your binded Java Bean and then, to answer your question : **"Kindly share the groovy expression to be used for this"**

```
<af:column inlineStyle="color:#{row.YourDate lt YourScope.YourBean.YourJavaPublicFunctionReturningCurrentDateMinus15?'green':'red'}!important" headerText="YourColumnHeader" id="c1">
    <af:outputText value="#{row.YourDate}" id="ot22">
        <af:convertDateTime pattern="#{bindings.YourIterator.hints.YourDate.format}"/>
    </af:outputText>
</af:column>
```

Note : To apply to all row the El need to be in the colum inlineStyle property and set as !important to bypass any other css classes.

Comment: I have a transient attribute date format and used groovy as adf.currentDate-15 and its returning the value current date minus - 15 . Is it possible to compare dates in expression language in property inspector.

Comment: Yes, you can compare date with lt, le, gt, ge, ... (see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm). However i don't think the adf.currentDate -15 would give you the currentDate minus 15 days. That's why i advised in the answer to make a java public function to return it.

Comment: I am just display datas from table in UI, How can i get value from java class with out calling that class brother?can you elaborate in detail?

Comment: Create a java class file. In your adfc-config.xml add your java class with the scope you want. Then add a public String YourJavaPublicFunctionReturningCurrentDateMinus15(){//Your code here} to your java class. The result of this function can then be accessible like this in EL YourScope.YourBean.YourJavaPublicFunctionReturningCurrentDateMinus15

Comment: I used the following code in java class                                                             public void currentdate (ActionEvent actionEvent){
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 Date date = new Date();
 System.out.println("Date :"+dateFormat.format(date));
        System.err.println("current date :");
        curr = dateFormat.format(date).toString();
        System.err.println(curr);}    I used output with value                                    #{backingBeanScope.backing_Fragments_SearchOrder.curr}  and i am not getting value in output text

Comment: It should return a String if you want to use it in your EL. Refer to : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/jstl-el-adf-093357.html

Comment: I used above mentioned class and its returning current date as string in curr variable and generated accessor for variable curr. Ihave output text and in its value i used expression language as             
#{backingBeanScope.backing_Fragments_SearchOrder.curr} and it's returning no value from the java class. Kindly help me to use the correct expression for returning value from java class every time when i load the page

Comment: Issue has been solved and thanks for your suggestion brother